# como puedo sumar columnas en array?

Tags: javascript, array

Hola me pueden ayudar con lo siguiente?
Como puedo mostrar que consola se uso mas de 300 horas? con reduce?

```
const Gamer = [
{ jugador: 6, Mes: 1, Consola: 1, año: 2019, horas: 10 }, 
{ jugador: 1, Mes: 3, Consola: 4, año: 2019, horas: 250 },
{ jugador: 5, Mes: 3, Consola: 2, año: 2020, horas: 20 },
{ jugador: 2, Mes: 2, Consola: 3, año: 2021, horas: 8},
{ jugador: 3, Mes: 1, Consola: 1, año: 2020, horas: 28 },
{ jugador: 5, Mes: 2, Consola: 2, año: 2017, horas: 15 },
{ jugador: 3, Mes: 3, Consola: 2, año: 2018, horas: 17 },
{ jugador: 6, Mes: 1, Consola: 1, año: 2019, horas: 12 }, 
{ jugador: 1, Mes: 3, Consola: 4, año: 2019, horas: 60 },
{ jugador: 5, Mes: 3, Consola: 2, año: 2020, horas: 20 },
{ jugador: 2, Mes: 2, Consola: 3, año: 2021, horas: 84},
{ jugador: 3, Mes: 1, Consola: 1, año: 2020, horas: 28 },
{ jugador: 5, Mes: 2, Consola: 2, año: 2017, horas: 15 },
{ jugador: 3, Mes: 3, Consola: 2, año: 2018, horas: 17 },

];
```

Esto hice

```
let gamer.consola => 300
```

console.log(gamer);

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has intenado hasta ahora? ¿Cómo has replicado el problema? Tu pregunta necesita mejoras

Answer (score 0):

No puede obtener las hora solo usando: `let gamer.consola => 300`. Necesita agrupar las consolas junto con las horas de cada consola y luego sumarlas para obtener lo que necesita.

Siga lo siguiente:

```
const mostUsed = Object.values(Gamer.reduce((acc,{Consola,horas})=>{
  acc[Consola]= acc[Consola] || {Consola, horas:[]} //horas: Array para usar el reduce anidado
  acc[Consola].horas.push(horas)
  return acc
},{}))
/*Sí comenta este segundo reduce puede ver las consolas y cada una de sus horas agrupadas,
solo cambie console.log(Object.entries(mostUsed).pop()) por console.log(mostUsed)
*/
.reduce((acc,{Consola,horas})=>({
  ...acc,[`Consola ${Consola}`]:horas.reduce((z,x) => z+x)
}),{})

console.log("La consola más usada es:​", Object.entries(mostUsed).pop())
```

Aprovechando los valores se toma el uso de `Object.values()` desestructurando, y se agrupa las consolas y cada una de sus horas usando el método `reduce()`. Luego nuevamente reagrupar con reduce + (reduce anidado) sumando las horas.

• Ya que ES6 retorna un objeto ordenado puede usar `pop()` para extraer el ultimo valor que será las consola más usada. En otro caso usar sort() por cada key.